# How can the complexity of this function be decreased?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, time-complexity

I got this function:

```
def get_sum_slices(a, sum)
  count = 0
  a.length.times do |n|
    a.length.times do |m|
      next if n > m
      count += 1 if a[n..m].inject(:+) == sum
    end
  end
  count
end
```

Given this  `[-2, 0, 3, 2, -7, 4]` array and `2` as sum it will return 2 because two sums of a slice equal 0 - `[2]` and `[3, 2, -7, 4]`. Anyone an idea on how to improve this to a O(N*log(N))?

Comment: What is this algorithm trying to achieve, and what is it doing in high level?

Comment: perhaps you could explain more explicitly what are you trying to achieve with this function

Comment: Well, it's a task for my studies in Computer Sciences. I need to reduce the complexity of this function to O(N*log(N)) or even better.

Comment: Is this a matching sub-array sum problem?

Comment: Why does it return "2"?  Is that the size of the first slice?

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with ruby, but it seems to me you are trying to find how many contiguous subarrays  that sums to `sum`.

Your code is doing a brute force of finding ALL subarrays - `O(N^2)` of those, summing them - O(N) each, and checking if it matches.

This totals in `O(N^3)` code.

It can be done more efficiently<sup>1</sup>:

define a new array `sums` as follows:

```
sums[i] = arr[0] + arr[1] + ... + arr[i]
```

It is easy to calculate the above in `O(N)` time. Note that with the assumption of non negative numbers - this `sums` array is sorted.

Now, iterate the `sums` array, and do a binary search for each element `sums[i]`, if there is some index `j` such that `sums[j]-sums[i] == SUM`. If the answer is true, add by one (more simple work is needed if array can contains zero, it does not affect complexity).

Since the search is binary search, and is done in `O(logN)` per iteration, and you do it for each element - you actually have `O(NlogN)` algorithm.

Similarly, but adding the elements in `sums` to a hash-set instead of placing them in a sorted array, you can reach `O(N)` average case performance, since seeking each element is now `O(1)` on average.

pseudo code:

```
input: arr , sum
output: numOccurances - number of contiguous subarrays  that sums to sum

currSum = 0
S = new hash set (multiset actually)
for each element x in arr:
   currSum += x
   add x to S
numOccurances= 0
for each element x in S:
   let k = number of occurances of sum-x in the hashset
   numOccurances += k
return numOccurances
```

Note that the hash set variant does not need the restriction of non-negative numbers, and can handle it as well.

---

(1) Assuming your array contains only non negative numbers.

Comment: How do I get `number of occurances of sum` in your pseudo code?

Comment: it's the number of occurances of `sum-x` (not `sum`), and it is a part of multiset implementation. Easy way to achieve it is by using a map/dictionary, and in the first loop - when adding to `S`, if `x` is already in `S`, add `1 + S[x]` (if it is not, set `S[x] = 1`), and then retrieving it is simply the value of `S[x]`. (remember `S` is a dictionary) Hope I'm clear.

Comment: Hashset has O(1) average case. What is worst case performance?

Comment: @hyades Usually `O(n)`, but one can improve it to `O(logn)` by placing [BSTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) in each "bin" instead of a linked list. In practice it is not done, since the worst case is too rare for proper hash function.

Comment: @hyades Also note, you can use a tree based multi-set instead of a hash based, and get O(nlogn) average&worst case.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the 1st approach. 
For the second one on a multi-set implemented as a bst, wont worst case be O(n) for a count operation?

Comment: Oh so it would be O(logn + count), if each node is implemented as a 3 pointer instead of usual 2 of bst.

Comment: Can't seem to be able to turn this into working Ruby code but well, thanks I guess :)

Comment: @Cojones for a very simple data you can use a simple hash function which takes care of negatives as well. Something like f(n) = n+50000. Hash it to an array of 100000. This would take of values from -50000 to +49999. Store the `k` value corresponding to the this hash.

Comment: Not helping, I seem to be missing something here.

Comment: @hyades I am not sure I am following you. a multiset is implemented as a map, where the key is the sum, and the value is the number of occurances of this sum. WHen doing a tree implementation, you have both `left, right, parent` for structure, the usual `key` for comparing, and an extra entry of `value` - the number of such sums.

Comment: ok I wasn't considering `parent` pointer. Was just referring to the `value` part.

Answer (score 1):

According to amit's algorithm  :

```
def get_sum_slices3(a, sum)
  s = a.inject([]) { |m, e| m << e + m.last.to_i }
  s.sort!
  s.count { |x| s.bsearch { |y| x - y == sum } }
end
```

Ruby uses quicksort which is nlogn in most cases

Comment: But still the same complexity?

Comment: @Cojones No, this is O(N^2), as opposed to O(N^3) your code achieves, and O(N) optimal

Comment: the complexity is definitly lower because there is no inject - cycle

Comment: @Cojones note that  This is most definetly NOT O(nlogn). there is a nested loop that repeats n*n times, this is O(N^2) code, which is indeed better than yours, but is significantly slower than O(N) or O(NlogN).

Comment: but its next on half of it

Comment: (1) `n*n/2 = n^2/2` which is in `O(n^2)`. (2)Also, the loop itself repeat n times for N and then n times for m, which is n^2 inner loop iterations.

Comment: for each `n`, the loop runs `m` times, making it O(n*m). What it does inside the loop is a constant time operation.

Comment: Now it is n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1 = n(n+1)/2 which is still in O(n^2).

Comment: seems you are right, I was thinking about it like bubble sorting and wrongly thought it is nlogn

Comment: bubble sort is also O(n^2)

Comment: I've refactored by amit's algorithm

Comment: Thanks, but it's now returning 3 instead of 4? Why did you add the sort! ? Removing it, makes it correct again.

Comment: pry(main)> get_sum_slices3 [-2, 0, 3, 2, -7, 4],0
=> 2

Comment: sort is needed for bsearch

Answer (score 0):

You should detail better what you're trying to achieve here. Anyway computing the number of subarray that have a specific sum could be done like this:

```
def get_sum_slices(a, sum) 
  count = 0
  (2..a.length).each do |n|
    a.combination(n).each do |combination|
      if combination.inject(:+) == sum
        count += 1
        puts combination.inspect
      end
    end
  end
  count
end
```

btw your example should return 6

```
irb> get_sum_slices [-2, 0, 3, 2, -7, 4], 0
[-2, 2]
[-2, 0, 2]
[3, -7, 4]
[0, 3, -7, 4]
[-2, 3, 2, -7, 4]
[-2, 0, 3, 2, -7, 4]
=> 6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. However, only a pair of integers is used for slices for that but I'm not quite show how to integrate that into your function.